# How to list all PHP variables in a file?

Tags: php, function, templates, variables

I have a PHP file with PHP Variables inside.
Example:

```
Hi <?=$username?>,
Can you please send me an email ?
```

I would like to list from an outside file, every PHP variables in this file.
Something that would return:

```
Array(
   'username'
);
```

I know there is a PHP function called `get_defined_vars`, but this is an external file.
Is there a way to get all PHP vars from an external file ?

Thank you

Comment: i would recommend a nice PHP IDE, all the good ones do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents()` and `preg_match_all()`:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.php'); 
preg_match_all('/\$[A-Za-z0-9_]+/', $file, $vars);

print_r($vars[0]);
```

Comment: Mostly good thank you. This also showed dollar amounts in the page, example $87, I escaped ints and now its fine.

Comment: When you have something in the code such as `$this->myMethod()` the regex above determines `$this-` as a variable. I think take the last hyphen out of the regex to fix? Also see the function in my answer which allows you to control whether to include variables contained in comments or not. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the expected accuracy a bit [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all) traversal will get you a list of variable basenames:

```
print_r(
    array_filter(
        token_get_all($php_file_content),
        function($t) { return $t[0] == T_VARIABLE; }
    )
);
```

Just filter out `[1]` from that array structure.

A bit less resilient, but sometimes still appropriate is a basic regex, which also allows to extract array variable or object syntax more easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
function extract_variables($content, $include_comments = false)
{
    $variables = [];

    if($include_comments)
    {
        preg_match_all('/\$[A-Za-z0-9_]+/', $content, $variables_);

        foreach($variables_[0] as $variable_)
            if(!in_array($variable_, $variables))
                $variables[] = $variable_;
    }
    else
    {
        $variables_ = array_filter
        (
            token_get_all($content),
            function($t) { return $t[0] == T_VARIABLE; }
        );

        foreach($variables_ as $variable_)
            if(!in_array($variable_[1], $variables))
                $variables[] = $variable_[1];
    }

    unset($variables_);
    return $variables;
}

// --------------

$content = file_get_contents("file.php");
$variables = extract_variables($content);

print_r($vars[0]);

// --------------
```