# How to write a regex to get all variables of a PHP file?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using source insight to get all php variables of a php file.

Comment: you will to explain a *little* more than that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all PHP variables in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873094/how-to-list-all-php-variables-in-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't suggest trying to use regex for this -- you'll come unstuck very quickly if you're parsing unknown code because of the complexities of the PHP language.

The language allows constructs such as variables used as function names, variable variables, several syntax options for variables inside strings, several different string syntaxes, all of which will catch you out, not to mention strings that contain dollar signs that aren't variables.

Instead, I would point you in the direction of using PHP's built-in tokeniser. This is part of the parser that interprets your PHP programs when they run.

Pass your code into the [PHP function `token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), and you will get in return a structured array of tokens, which includes all the variables in use. It should be a lot easier to sort through this array than to try to parse the code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**\u0024(\w*)**

Because $ is a special character in REGEX, you can use its unicode representation 0024.

Without Regex - You can get all defined variables through this PHP function:  [get-defined-vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php).