# Retrieve values configuration settings MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

How can I retrieve the values of (all) MediaWiki [configuration settings](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings_(alphabetical)) and show them in a wikipage for testing? A bit like [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Comment: What about using Extension:Configure to Display (and Modify) them? See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Configure

Answer (score 3):

[`Manual:GetConfiguration.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:GetConfiguration.php):

```
echo `php maintenance/getConfiguration.php --format vardump`;
```

Options:

```
Script specific parameters:
    --format: json, php, serialize, vardump
    --iregex: same as --regex but case insensitive
    --regex: regex to filter variables with
    --settings: Space-separated list of wg* variables
```

Comment: Note that this script will simply print all global variables matching a certain regex (by default those starting with `wm?g`). This will probably give you quite a few global variables that are not exactly configuration settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873094/how-to-list-all-php-variables-in-a-file) to fetch all variables from [DefaultSettings.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/includes/DefaultSettings.php), and then loop through them to print out their results.

Maybe something like this:

```
global $IP;
$defaultSettingsFile = file_get_contents($IP . 'DeafultSettings.php'); 
preg_match_all('/\$[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/', $defaultSettingsFile, $param);
foreach( $param as $p ){
  echo "$p:  ${$p}\n";
}
```