# MediaWiki Hook for Installing Extension

Tags: mediawiki

I did some research on MediaWiki hooks.

To the best of my knowledge, the only hook for adding/updating database tables is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates.

However, I need a hook that fires on installing a new extension. How do I achieve that? I'd like to execute a `CREATE TABLE` statement only once - when the extension is installed. Installing an extension doesn't require a MediaWiki update, which is why the above hook does not suit my needs.

**EDIT**

To clarify: I'm developing an extension that requires access to a custom table in the database. That's why I need to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement whenever this extension is installed.

Answer (score 0):

First: As you have noticed, there is no such hook. You will need to do the check for installed extensions by a cron job (if it's your server), or on, say, each 100th request to the wiki, using the [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue/For_developers) (if you are doing this in an extension).

From there, you have a few options, depending on if you need to catch every single extension, or just most of them:

1. Check for registered extensions, with something like: 
   `$registry = ExtensionRegistry::getInstance();`
   `$extensions = $registry->loaded();`
   This will work extensions using the [new style](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extension_registration). For older versions, check the global variable `$wgExtensionCredits` for registered extensions. Note that nothing prevents an extensions from running without registering. In fact, there are a lot of extensions like that.
2. [Parse LocalSettings.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815179/retrieve-values-configuration-settings-mediawiki/27867817#27867817), and check for old and new style extension loading with a regex. Very dirty, but it's actually the way e.g. the maintainance script [getConfiguration.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:GetConfiguration.php) does it. You need to check for lines like this:
   `wfLoadExtension( 'FooBar' );`
   and this:
   `wfLoadExtensions( ['Foo', 'Bar'] );`
   and this:
   `require_once "$IP/extensions/Foo/Bar.php";` Note however that it is possible to use other directories for extensions, and that modern skins in fact behave like extensions too.
3. If you need to track a certain family of extensions, and you can make sure they all use Composer, the parse [`$IP/composer.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#json-schema) for installed extensions.

Comment: Thank you, Leo! I only need to track one extension - the extension I'm developing. After installing the extension by adding `require_once "$IP/extensions/Foo/Bar.php";` to `LocalSettings.php`, I would like to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Then I would simply have created a special page, `Special:InitializeXXX`, and instructed users to go there to finalize the install. This is how e.g. Semantic MediaWiki [does it](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Special:SMWAdmin) (and many other extensions that need to make changes in the DB layout)

Comment: Why not instruct the user to run the update script or go through the process of "mw-config" in the web browser?

Comment: @Florian: I want the extension installation process to be as simple as possible. Since installing the extension doesn't necessarily go along with updating MediaWiki, I can't really use the update script (and the `LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates` hook). Which is why I'm inclined to use a special page as per @Leo's comment.

Comment: @bernland I don't know, how decentralizing the database setup and installation of extensions would make it easier for a wiki sysadmin to install an extension. The common way (both, for developers and for wiki sysadmins) is to upload the extension directory to extensions/, putting the require_once line (or wfLoadExtensions()) into the LocalSettings.php and run the update script. Having it's own special page for each extension makes the whole wiki overloaded and much more complicated in sum, even if it would make sense for one extension only :) ...

Comment: ... It's also not a good way for upgrading an extension to instruct the user to run the special page again for any schema updates for the extension. Normally an extension get's updated alongside with a mediawiki core upgrade (which usually needs the update script), so it's likely, that a wiki sysadmin forget to run your own special page and will use an old, outdated and maybe error prone database schema. The MediaWiki installer would take care of running all db updates you define. So I would really recommend to use MediaWiki's own updater.

Comment: @Florian: You're absolutely right, thank you! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Update.php#Details) and found out that the LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates hook is exactly what I am looking for.

```
# Schema updates for update.php
$wgHooks['LoadExtensionSchemaUpdates'][] = 'fnMyHook';
function fnMyHook( DatabaseUpdater $updater ) {
    $updater->addExtensionTable( 'tablename',
        __DIR__ . '/table.sql' );
    return true;
}
```

When running `$ php update.php` for the first time after installing the extension, the script executes the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Then, for consecutive executions, the update script just notes that the table already exists.