# Import variables in file into array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Basically, I have multiple files containing loads of PHP variables, and i'm trying to create a way to read them in to a subarray for each file with each variable being in the array.

```
<?php

$data = Array();

$getData = glob('siteData/*.vars.php', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($getData as $tempData) {

    $dataKey = str_replace(".vars.php", "", str_replace("siteData/", "", $tempData));
    $data[$dataKey] = Array();

    //foreach varaible in file

        //$data[$dataKey][$varaibleName] = $variable

}

?>
```

The bit commented out is the bit I need help with as I have no idea how to do it.
Please help, TIA.

Comment: For context,

The variables are stored in separate files by category so the client can find and edit them easily, the variable names again giving direction and there are comments to clarify. I am then importing them all into one array to then replace their holders in a site template. Like so:

`$siteLayout = file_get_contents(""); //Will be site template

foreach($data as $dataKey => $dataSub) {
 foreach($dataSub as $dataSubKey => $dataVar) {
  $searchVar = "${".$dataKey.":".$dataSubKey."}";
  $siteLayout = str_replace($searchVar, $dataVar, $siteLayout);
 }
}`

Comment: Files edited by your user that you load into your script to be used as variables in your script!! **I see tears before bedtime**

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's template data, and I will want to clean the variables when they are imported. Thus very little damage can be done, other than the client f***ing over their settings for their template.

Comment: Exactly my point in a ball bag

Comment: @RiggsFolly When we send it out to the client with their variables setup, they will be told changing them could break the site for them, and we will keep a copy of them as well!

Comment: I know its more effort, but I would write them a little from end so you can limit the damage the user can do, and maybe provide a quick `get out of jail free` mechanism along the lines of `restore last good settings`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I might, but the client can just contact us if they wanted their old settings. Anyway, all of this can only happen if I work out a way to import the variables.

Comment: Does this help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic Yes thank you, but how would I do this for just one external file?

Comment: Maybe like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873094/how-to-list-all-php-variables-in-a-file

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic Great, but how do I get their values as well? (I'm quite bad at regex). TIA.

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic I got it. '/\$[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\s?=\s?["\'].+["\'];/'

Comment: I recommend RegexBuddy for regex https://www.regexbuddy.com/

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of help, the answering code is as follows:

```
<?php

$data = Array();

$getData = glob('siteData/*.vars.php', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($getData as $tempData) {

    $dataKey = str_replace(".vars.php", "", str_replace("siteData/", "", $tempData));
    $data[$dataKey] = Array();

    $dataFile = file_get_contents($tempData); 
    preg_match_all('/\$[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\s?=\s?["\'].+["\'];/', $dataFile, $dataVars);

    $dataVars = $dataVars[0];

    foreach($dataVars as $variable) {

        $variable = explode("=", $variable);
        $varaibleName = ltrim(trim($variable[0]), "$");
        $variable = trim(trim(rtrim(trim($variable[1]), ";"), "'"), '"');

        $data[$dataKey][$varaibleName] = $variable;

    }

}

print_r($data);

?>
```